# How to set a flag in array of objects and render items

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to render the particular object in an array. Where should i set the flag?Need Single loop

```
mappedData = (data) => {
return data.map((item) => {...logic}
}
```

Here is my  sample object which returns

```
item:[
{id: 1, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
{id: 2, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com', isFirst:false},
{id: 3, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:true},
{id: 4, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'bar@foo.com', isFirst:false},
{id: 5, entry_id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'joe@ocean.com', isFirst:true},
{id: 6, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:false},
{id: 7, entry_id: 2, name: 'test', email: 'foo@bar.com', isFirst:false},
];
```

How to set flag? and render 2 different div's which contains entry_id 1 in div and entry_id 2  in another div

```
render(){
return(
if(this.mappedData.entry_id =1){
<div>All entry_id 1 data should appear</div>
}
if(this.mappedData.entry_id =2){
<div>All entry_id 2  data should appear</div>
}
```

Most welcome on different solution with single loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to have your two `div`s separately and then run individual loops in each with returning `null` (in your false case):

Code could look like this, (assuming `item` is your array):

```
<div>
{item.map((x) => {
  if(x.entry_id === 1){
      return <p>{x.name}</p>
  }
 return null;

})}
</div>
<div>
{item.map((x) => {
  if(x.entry_id === 2){
     return <p>{x.name}</p>
  }
 return null;
})}
</div>
```

If `item` is an object property, just replace `item.map` with `data.item.map`

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-germain-0r6f3?file=/src/App.js)

1. You can also make separate loops at top by filtering and show them.
2. You can also [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array and then map inside the curly braces, if you are concerned about the `null`

**EDIT:**

OP wanted a solution with single loop. It can be achieved using this:

```
  let div1 = [];
  let div2 = [];

  item.forEach((x) => {
    if (x.entry_id === 1) {
      div1.push(<p key={x.email}>{x.name}</p>);
    } else {
      div2.push(<p key={x.email}>{x.name}</p>);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        <>
          {div1}
          {div2}
        </>
      }
    </div>
  );
```

[Updated Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ganguly-rbdq0?file=/src/App.js:58-1010)

Comment: Thank you @Tushar but i need iterated logic seperately because i use other logic over there, Since both the values are coming in the same object i though of using flag

Comment: I didn't understand. You want only one loop?

Comment: Yes i want one loop

Comment: Any updates on this single loop setting flag

Comment: One way to do this is : https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ganguly-rbdq0?file=/src/App.js:0-1013